# How to get other resource in the same project in java plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, xtext

[image]

For example, I have three files in the same project (in my runtime), now my program are working on one of them and I can get the URL of it (platform:/resouce/orginal.dmodel), how could I get the other two files (i.e. resources)?

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve, why you want to get the URIs

Comment: Are you trying to get the file names of other files in the directory? Or you already know the names, but don't know how to load the other two?